# configService.get<T>('key') fails on type cast and joi on validation

Tags: typescript, nestjs, joi

I created a custom configuration file for my NestJs REST API. This is a simple example for the port the application is listening on.

I have a .env file with the content

```
SERVER_PORT = 3000
```

An example for my configuration file

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';

@Injectable()
export class ServerConfigService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    const { error } = Joi.object({
      port: Joi.number()
        .port()
        .required(),
    }).validate({ port: this.port });

    if (error) { // no error thrown
      throw error;
    }

    console.log(typeof this.port); // type is string but should be number
  }

  public get port(): number {
    return this.configService.get<number>('SERVER_PORT');
  }
}
```

I would expect the ports type to be `number` but it's still a `string`. So two things come to my mind:

- I call `this.configService.get<T>('key')` as shown [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice) with a generic type. Why does it still return a string? I would expect a type cast.
- I use joi for the validation as described [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#schema-validation). I would expect joi throwing an error.

The port variable might be a bad example because Nest is able to deal with a port of type string. But other parts expect numbers and throw errors if a config variable should be a number but is of type string.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Is that `get()` method actually generic? Looking at the source, [it's not](https://github.com/nestjsx/nestjs-config/blob/master/src/module/config.service.ts#L97). Even if it was generic, It's probably actually a string and I doubt the implementation would be able to perform that conversion, generic parameters are not usable at runtime and would not be able to do anything with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The linked NestJsx repository is not an official one I think? And why would I provide a type then =? Further why does Joi validate successfully .. At least this one should throw an error ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realized that the more I dug in. I can't find the source for that `ConfigService` class. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: But, the second part of my comment still stands, all you can really tell the compiler there is that the the return value should be treated as a number, but it doesn't necessarily mean that it will be a number.

Comment: Ok [found it](https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/master/lib/config.service.ts), it definitely doesn't perform any conversions, it simply gets the value. The runtime type will be however it is read, which is probably all strings. You'll need to convert yourself.

Comment: Hmm I think the docs are confusing then...

Comment: but why does joi pass the validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you found using the `ConfigService` is very misleading. What's misleading is the generic type parameter. The type you pass it only affects what the return value is treated as. The actual runtime type will be whatever the type is when it was read.

NestJs uses `dotenv` to read the config files and all values are simply read as strings. No conversions are made.

You should be using it like this:

```
public get port(): number {
  return +this.configService.get('SERVER_PORT');
}
```

[ConfigService source](https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/master/lib/config.service.ts#L37)
[dotenv source](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js#L37)

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks for the example. But why does joi throw no error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nestjs or joi so I can't tell you for sure. But if I were to venture a guess, joi is smart enough to know that a string representation of a number is valid. If you set a server port that is not a number (before doing this conversion), it would likely fail.

Answer (score 1):

As written above this is highly misleading and should be changed. There's no reason why the returned value should be explicitly casted if the generic indicates a concrete type.

What I don't get is why there is no type casting exception on:

const myNumber:number = this.configService.get('PROPERTY_PATH');

Even if ConfigService effectively returns a string, how can it be assigned as-is to a number? In fact myNumber will effectively be a string even though it is explicitly defined as number. This is a Typescript issue just as much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the Joi schema with the option `{convert: true}`?  This is supposed to convert a numeric string validated against a `Joi.number()` into an actual `number`.  [Doc link](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#number)